# Android app to record screen unlock times and dates to a log file?

Tags: android, login, lockscreen

I am looking for an Android app to record screen unlock (and lock) times and dates to a log file on the system. Thanks.

I have found the [Unlock Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.g00dapps.x6xi.unlocklog) but it does not list the lock times. The lock times are also important because they give you an idea of the amount of time the intruder spent on your phone (the time between the unlock time and the lock time). Otherwise you cannot know.

Suppose someone gets a hold of your phone while it is not locked. If it were left alone, you know the screen saver might have kicked in within say 10 minutes. If the period of time is longer than 10 minutes then you know someone has been tampering with it.

Comment: Should is also be able to display this log file in-app, or just write to it?

Comment: And should the log be kept on your device? Then [take a look here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_450) :)